# Powershell Get-Command not working in script

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell v7.1.4.

If I run Get-Command from the prompt then powershell finds the command no problem -

[image: get-command]

If I place this in a script, the Get-Command does not work.

```
    try {                                                                                                                          
        Get-Command pandoc -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Could not find pandoc, cannot generate documentation."
        Exit 1
    }
```

Running this script generates -

> Write-Error: Could not find pandoc, cannot generate documentation.

So, why does get-command not work correctly in the context of a script?

### Edit 1

An update to answer some of the comments.  First is the full script followed by the output, including an update recommended in the comment ($_ | Format-List -Force)

```
function VerifyPandocExists {
    try {                                                                                                                           ─╯
        Get-Command pandoc -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Could not find pandoc"
        $_ | Format-List -Force
        Exit 1
    }
}

pandoc --version
VerifyPandocExists
```

Script output.  Looking at the error output, I notice it states -

> The term '─╯' is not recognized as a

That funny looking character '─╯' looks like something from my oh-my-posh prompt (not sure if relevant...):

[image]

```
pandoc.exe 2.14.2
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22, texmath 0.12.3.1, skylighting 0.11,
citeproc 0.5, ipynb 0.1.0.1
User data directory: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2021 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
Write-Error: C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ProgrammingStandards\mkdocs.ps1:12
Line |
  12 |  VerifyPandocExists
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find pandoc.


Exception             : System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term '─╯' is not recognized as a
                        name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
                        Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
                        try again.
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
                        funcContext, Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
                        frame)
                           at
                        System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
                        frame)
                           at
                        System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
                        frame)
TargetObject          : ─╯
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (─╯:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at VerifyPandocExists, C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ProgrammingStandards\mkdocs.ps1: line 2
                        at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ProgrammingStandards\mkdocs.ps1: line 12
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: Are you sure that in your real code the `Get-Command` call is the only statement in your `try` block and that isn't a _different_ statement that triggers the `catch` block?

Comment: Also: Is `pandoc.exe` in your path in the PowerShell session where you are running `Get-Command`, but not in the path in the PowerShell session where you are running the script?

Comment: @mklement0 yeah the script just has that bit of code in it ATM.  Yeah pandoc.exe is in the path, I can run it fine from within the script.

Comment: If you place `$_ | Format-List -Force` before the `Exit 1` statement in your `catch` block, what error specifics are reported?

Comment: @mklement0 I've updated Q providing more details including the Format-List command.

Comment: Why do you need to call `Get-Command` in the first place? Why not just try running whatever you run and check `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards?

Comment: @n0rd I don't.  The idea was to provide a nice error message - which I could have done that way.  But then I discovered Get-Command is not working the way I think it should.  So I want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your script line 2 (`try {`), there are a lot of spaces and then it ends with that character: `─╯` (Notice the horizontal scroll bar in the code snippet in your question). I.e. Powershell simply complains about unexpected characters in your script. Remove them and it will work.

Comment: Perfect thanks!  Not sure how I overlooked that.